# Alterar texto no header de acordo a pagina aberta

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Preciso alterar o texto do header toda vez que mudar de página. Alguem poderia me ajudar??/

Comment: O que você já possui?

Comment: controllers e páginas

Comment: Poderia incluir os trechos relevantes do código? Com header, você quer dizer o title da página? Ou algum elemento que é usado como header?

Comment: Tenho um texto de cabeçalho em cada página, gostaria que esse texto aparecesse no header. Toda vez que abrisse uma página o header mostrasse o texto referente a mesma. Visto que o header é o mesmo para todas as páginas, queria fazer isso dinamicamente via angularjs

Comment: Posta o que você ja tem ai, como é seu header e seu app angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `$window.document.title = "seuTituloAqui";` dentro de uma função chamada ao carregar aquela view, por exemplo utilizando `ng-init`